# Using facet in R with SHINY

Tags: r, shiny

How do i create a histogram for a group of data based on their column names. The column names are input from the user. Looking at my code, selecteddatabase frame is the column names the user requested with their result in them. I want to create a histogram for each one but how do i take into account that the columns specified could be an infinite number?......i tried looping with facet, that did not work. It only plotted the last column.

[My try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WzNV.png)

[SelectedDatabaseFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc9ch.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  `ggplot()`, as part of the tidyverse, expects [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) data.  Your data are not tidy because there is information in the column names.  You need to convert your data to long format using `pivot_longer()`.  Then you can define facets based on the column that contains the original column names.

Comment: Also, please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: Greetings! It would be helpful to have a minimal reproducible dataset included in your question. One way of doing that is by using the `dput` command. You can find out how to do this here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg